# make: g++: Permission denied with CXX = g++ but not CXX = /usr/bin/g++

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile, g++

Recently, I realise most of my packages that require g++ and use Makefile will build fail with the same error message:
`make: g++ Permission denied`

And I found out it is because of `CXX = g++` which suppose to work normally, I don't know why it is different in my system.

I tested with two Makefiles.
The first one:

```
CXX=g++

all:
    which $(CXX)
    $(CXX) -v
```

will result into

```
which g++
/usr/bin/g++
g++ -v
make: g++: Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:5: all] Error 127
```

The second Makefile:

```
CXX=/usr/bin/g++

all:
    which $(CXX)
    $(CXX) -v
```

will have the correct result

```
which /usr/bin/g++
/usr/bin/g++
/usr/bin/g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-bootstrap --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-cet=auto --enable-checking=release --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-multilib --enable-plugin --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-werror --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto --enable-link-serialization=1
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 12.1.0 (GCC)
```

In the first Makefile, `which $(CXX)` still result in `/usr/bin/g++` which is still correct so I don't understand what is the problem here.

For my system information. I am using Arch Linux, GCC works fine in Makefile which is the reason why I only know g++ has this problem now so I don't know when this problem started.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Any alias defined for g++? Run `strace -f make` and see what it actually executes.

Comment: I didn't know the existence of `strace`. Thank you very much. So apparently, it links to a different g++ that is a folder and not even real g++ so it cause that error.

Comment: but do you know why it link to a different path even though `which $(CXX)` return `/usr/bin/g++`

Comment: What happens if you just type `g++ --version` in your shell?

Comment: Could you also check your `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables with `> echo $PATH` and `> echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: well it works normally that's why I didn't think PATH was the reasons
g++ only breaks while using with makefile.
Anyway, I already fix it after modifying that PATH's orders.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly because some directory on your `$PATH` has a *directory* named `g++` in it, and this directory appears before `/usr/bin`.

So, if you run run `ls -ld <dir>/g++` for every directory `<dir>` in `$PATH` starting with the first one, one of them will be a directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x ...   <dir>/g++
^ directory!!
```

Due to a bug in the gnulib library that GNU make is using, it will treat a directory found on the PATH differently from the way the shell will treat it; it won't skip it, like the shell will, and will instead try to "run" it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, after resetting the order of $PATH, it works normally now

Comment: A better solution is to locate the directory containing a `g++` subdirectory and either remove that `g++` subdirectory, or take that directory out of your `PATH`.  The bin directories on `PATH` should contain binaries, not subdirectories.

Comment: I needed some binaries inside that folder but didn't realise there is also a subdirectory named g++ inside it. I will probably will add the binary files to the path instead of the whole folder

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but you can't put actual files on your PATH.  Every entry in the PATH is considered a directory and executables are looked for in that directory.  If you put a file pathname into PATH it will be ignored.  The question is not whether you should have the directory containing the programs you need on your PATH: obviously you should.  The question is why you have a `g++` subdirectory in a directory on your PATH.  Having that subdirectory is a bad idea and should be avoided.

Comment: well yes, I just realised I can't do that. For the reason why I have g++ in my path, my uni requires us to use the library Splashkit which has the binary file skm. So I just added the folder into PATH but they also have a subdirectory named g++ for some reason. Well I temporary solved the problem by reordering the path so that make file still select /usr/bin/g++ first.